# API responds with different JSON types each time

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm getting data from a JSON API. And I'm using GSON to parse the data for my Android app. The problem is, the value for the same variable is a JSONArray in one case, but in another case, it is a JSONObject. Hence I'm unable to write the Java classes which GSON could use to parse the data.

**First response - "direction" is an array**

```
{  
     "route":{  
     "time_min":"10",
     "directions":{  
     "direction":[ 

        {  
           "direction_description":"Dummy text.",
           "direction_number":"1"
        },

        {  
           "direction_description":"Dummy text.",
           "direction_number":"2"
        },

        {  
           "direction_description":"Dummy text.",
           "direction_number":"3"
        }

      ]}}}
```

**Second response - "direction" is an object**

```
{  
     "route":{  
     "time_min":"10",
     "directions":{  
     "direction": 
        {  
           "direction_description":"Dummy text.",
           "direction_number":"1"
        }

       }}}
```

How should I write the Java classes which GSON will use for parsing?

Comment: What are the differences you are talking about ?

Comment: The two responses you posted are exactly the same.

Comment: didnt see any difference ???

Comment: When array is returned, I need to create a List of an object. When object is returned, I need to create only an object but with the same variable name. I can't use the same variable name twice in the same class. "@SerializedName" annotation is not working too.

Comment: Missing `"` at time_min

Comment: @LeoAso @ JJG I've edited now.. sorry for the confusion... now it's different

Comment: i think you are misunderstanding you json. you have 1 ) JSONObject with name `directions` (with a s). 2) an JSONArray with name `direction` (without a s).

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez The problem is... both array and object use the same variable name... It's just that either one of those is returned each time

Comment: @Anand it cannot be true. since your `directions` array reside inside your `direction` object.. you must be getting both then.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez Unfortunately, the API that I'm using is returning data in such a confusing way... I understand it's wrong... But this is how I'm getting the data

Comment: When there is more than one direction, array is returned. When there is only one direction, object is returned.

Answer (score 1):

First, Try opting JSONObject

```
JSONObject jOBJ = parentOBJ.optJSONObject("direction");
```

If the value of jOBJ is `null` Try getting `JSONArray` -

```
JSONOArray jARR = parentOBJ.optJSONArray("direction");
```

PS,
Use `try.. catch()` when needed.

Comment: I'm unable to do this since I'm using GSON for parsing and not doing it manually. Will I be able to make it work if I do the parsing manually?

Comment: Of course, get and `object` or an `array` first, then serialize `json` using `gson`. Or you can do the whole thing manually without using `gson`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **`instance of`**.

> The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an
>   instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface).

```
Object obj= jsonOBJ.get("direction");
if (obj instanceof JSONArray) 
  {


  }
else
  {
   // It's JSONObject 
  }
```

Comment: I'm unable to do this since I'm using GSON for parsing and not doing it manually. Will I be able to make it work if I do the parsing manually?